# PHP Version is not set via ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I have an ARM template, shown below, for a Web App, with a Web Configuration. I want to set the Stack to PHP and the version to 7.4 as seen in the Portal but upon Deployment that is not set. What am I missing.

Desired configuration:

[image]

The Result:

[image]

The template:

```
    "resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "name": "[variables('appServicePlanPortalName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "kind": "app",
        "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "name": "[parameters('webAppNameLegacy')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanPortalName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanPortalName'))]",
            "reserved": false,
            "isXenon": false,
            "hyperV": false,
            "siteConfig": {},
            "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false,
            "clientAffinityEnabled": true,
            "clientCertEnabled": false,
            "hostNamesDisabled": false,
            "containerSize": 0,
            "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": 0,
            "httpsOnly": false,
            "redundancyMode": "None"
        }
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppNameLegacy'), '/web')]",
        "location": "West Europe",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('webAppNameLegacy'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "numberOfWorkers": 1,
            "defaultDocuments": [
                "Default.htm",
                "Default.html",
                "Default.asp",
                "index.htm",
                "index.html",
                "iisstart.htm",
                "default.aspx",
                "index.php"
            ],                
            "phpVersion": "7.4",
            "requestTracingEnabled": false,
            "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
            "remoteDebuggingVersion": "VS2019",
            "httpLoggingEnabled": false,
            "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
            "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
            "azureStorageAccounts": {},
            "scmType": "None",
            "webSocketsEnabled": true,
            "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
            "virtualApplications": [
                {
                    "virtualPath": "/",
                    "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
                    "preloadEnabled": true
                }
            ],
            "loadBalancing": "LeastRequests",
            "experiments": {
                "rampUpRules": []
            },
            "autoHealEnabled": false,
            "localMySqlEnabled": false,
            "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
                {
                    "ipAddress": "Any",
                    "action": "Allow",
                    "priority": 1,
                    "name": "Allow all",
                    "description": "Allow all access"
                }
            ],
            "scmIpSecurityRestrictions": [
                {
                    "ipAddress": "Any",
                    "action": "Allow",
                    "priority": 1,
                    "name": "Allow all",
                    "description": "Allow all access"
                }
            ],
            "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain": false,
            "http20Enabled": true,
            "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
            "ftpsState": "AllAllowed",
            "reservedInstanceCount": 0
        }
    }
]
```

Later Edit: there is a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/6487) about it.

Comment: Did you create the app service first, and then deploy the template?

Comment: Initially, no, it is created via `serverfarms` resource. Afterwards, during various tests, I've deleted only the web app and deployed the template again. It is supposed to be a windows machine, not linux.

Comment: So, the issue is happened when you deleted the web app and re-deploy the template, is that right?

Comment: It happens on both cases: 1. delete everything and start over. 2. Delete only the Web App.

Comment: Just for a test, please try to create the php 4.7 app service first, and then try to deploy the template to the app service again.

Comment: How to create the php app service first? Manually? The settings are not overridden by the deployment if this is what you're trying to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also be passing the `CURRENT_STACK` parameter set to `php` as part of the `siteconfig` `metadata` property in the ARM template.

```
...
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "name": "[parameters('sites_app_name')]",
        "location": "Central US",
        "kind": "app",
        "properties": {
            ...
            "siteConfig": {
                "metadata": [
                    {
                        "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
                        "value": "php"
                    }
                ]
            },
            ...
        }
    },
...
```

Here is the full template for creating a Web app with PHP 7.4 as the runtime stack:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "sites_app_name": {
            "defaultValue": "php-app-74",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "serverfarms_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "<server-farms-id>",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "name": "[parameters('sites_app_name')]",
            "location": "Central US",
            "kind": "app",
            "properties": {
                "enabled": true,
                "hostNameSslStates": [
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_app_name'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
                        "sslState": "Disabled",
                        "hostType": "Standard"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_app_name'), '.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
                        "sslState": "Disabled",
                        "hostType": "Repository"
                    }
                ],
                "serverFarmId": "[parameters('serverfarms_externalid')]",
                "reserved": false,
                "isXenon": false,
                "hyperV": false,
                "siteConfig": {
                    "metadata": [
                        {
                            "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
                            "value": "php"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false,
                "clientAffinityEnabled": true,
                "clientCertEnabled": false,
                "hostNamesDisabled": false,
                "containerSize": 0,
                "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": 0,
                "httpsOnly": false,
                "redundancyMode": "None"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_app_name'), '/web')]",
            "location": "Central US",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_app_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "numberOfWorkers": 1,
                "defaultDocuments": [
                    "Default.htm",
                    "Default.html",
                    "Default.asp",
                    "index.htm",
                    "index.html",
                    "iisstart.htm",
                    "default.aspx",
                    "index.php",
                    "hostingstart.html"
                ],
                "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.0",
                "phpVersion": "7.4",
                "requestTracingEnabled": false,
                "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
                "httpLoggingEnabled": false,
                "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
                "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
                "publishingUsername": "$php-app",
                "azureStorageAccounts": {},
                "scmType": "None",
                "use32BitWorkerProcess": true,
                "webSocketsEnabled": false,
                "alwaysOn": false,
                "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
                "virtualApplications": [
                    {
                        "virtualPath": "/",
                        "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
                        "preloadEnabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "loadBalancing": "LeastRequests",
                "experiments": {
                    "rampUpRules": []
                },
                "autoHealEnabled": false,
                "localMySqlEnabled": false,
                "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
                    {
                        "ipAddress": "Any",
                        "action": "Allow",
                        "priority": 1,
                        "name": "Allow all",
                        "description": "Allow all access"
                    }
                ],
                "scmIpSecurityRestrictions": [
                    {
                        "ipAddress": "Any",
                        "action": "Allow",
                        "priority": 1,
                        "name": "Allow all",
                        "description": "Allow all access"
                    }
                ],
                "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain": false,
                "http20Enabled": false,
                "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
                "ftpsState": "AllAllowed",
                "reservedInstanceCount": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_app_name'), '/', parameters('sites_app_name'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "location": "Central US",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_app_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "siteName": "php-app-74",
                "hostNameType": "Verified"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```